# scala read file and split and then save into val

Tags: scala

I have a hello.txt

hello.txt

```
     [,1]
1       2
2       2
5      12
6       4
```

and here is scala code:

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("/home/winsome/share/hello.txt")
val ratings = textFile.map { line => 
    val fields = line.split(" ")  
    val (id, linksStr) = (fields(0).toInt, fields(1).toInt)
    println(id)        //1 2 5 6
    printlin(linkStr)  //2 2 12 4
 }
```

`println(id)` and `printlin(linkStr)` do nothing , Please tell me how to display the format I want
thank you

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try this :
Reading all the lines from your file
Split the line by space and map into your ids and lnkstrs and then print it.

```
val lines = io.Source.fromFile("hello.txt").getLines()

    lines.map { x =>
      val value = x.split(" ")
      (value.head.toInt, value.last.toInt)
    }.foreach { z =>
      println(z._1)
      println(z._2)
    }
```

Comment: The OP's using Spark, though

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each line is tab-separated consider a splitting like this,

```
line.split("\t")
```

Yet simpler, without separator assumptions, split alphanumerical *words*,

```
line.split("\\W+")
```

Also for extracting each *word* consider

```
val Array(a,b,_*) = line.split("\\W+")
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 possible problems in your code. First, are you sure you have only whitespace as a delimiter? Let's use any numbers of non digits for sure: `line.split("[^\\d]+")`. Second, how about the first line `[, 1]` - it has different structure, so you should delete this line. Third problem is that you use `map` for side effect action. `map` must be pure-functional, use it only for data transformation. For printing to console use `foreach`. Let's wrap up:

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("/home/winsome/share/hello.txt")
val ratings = textFile
  .map ( line => {
    val fields = line.split("[^\\d]+")  
    (fields(0).toInt, fields(1).toInt)
  })
  .foreach(println)
```

Comment: So I should delete the ````[, 1]````?  Can I pass this line

Comment: You can filter this line `textFile.filter(line =>  !(line contains "[, 1]").map(...)`